# connectycube chat implementation chart in react native without redux

Tags: react-native, connectycube

Dear friend I create chat app in  react native by connectycube
but when 2 opponents connect to a dialog by this code message didnot send to server

```
msg.id = ConnectyCube.chat.send(opponentId, msg,(error)=>{
  alert(JSON.stringify(error))
});
```

but when a opponent connect to chat and another opponent not connect message send work correctly

Comment: Any specific error you receive?

Comment: No, I don't receive any error

Comment: Ok, then please enable logs in SDK and share it here, so we will check and see what's going on

Comment: Dear Rubycon I send you my log

Comment: <message id="5dc98de8e8550e3ce3000000" type="3" from="218307-1233@chat.connectycube.com/1204607085-chat-177857"
 xmlns="jabber:client" to="218308-1233@chat.connectycube.com">
 <body
  xmlns="jabber:client">aloooo
 </body>
 <extraParams
  xmlns="jabber:client">
  <save_to_history>1</save_to_history>
  <dialog_id>5dc5f0a7ca8bf41b3c21b76b</dialog_id>
  <sender_id>218307</sender_id>
 </extraParams>
 <date_sent/>
</message>'

Answer (score 0):

I see what's wrong here.

type="3" - it should be type="chat" for 1-1 and type="groupchat" for groupchat